# Android: Button to new screen and show sql data

Tags: android, sql, android-activity, screen

I am working a project. I have lots of word text data and don't want to add layout and class for each one. I want to use sqlite, but don't know how. For example, there is a button, id is cat.

When clicking the cat button, a new screen opens and shows information of cat. One layout, one class, but lots of screens. The data must come from sql because there are too many animals.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have given the answer already yourself: SQL database may be your friend. Work yourself through [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) and see how far that brings you. You'll have to manipulate the UI from code, that is doable as well.

Another approach you might want to consider is putting everything in XML into strings.xml file(s). This depends a bit on the size and structure of your data. From code you can reach this using `getString( R.id.blah )`.

Answer (score 0):

Call other screen passing values.
In the button click do:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondScreen.class).putExtra('Identify', 'Value'));
```

In the Second Screen do:

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra('Identify');
```

Now, take that value and make the query in  SqLite and display the result.